# Vim + Tex_SmartQuoteOpen for csquote

Tags: vim, vim-latex

with vim-latex for vim, there is a two variables `g:Tex_SmartQuoteOpen` and `g:Tex_SmartQuoteClose` which meaning repleacment text for " at the begining/and of a citation.

Default value are ``'' + one <++> in case of input in the same time.

I would like to configure for `\enquote` of the `csquotes` package. So I have tried

```
let g:Tex_SmartQuoteOpen="\enquote{"
let g:Tex_SmartQuoteClose="}"
```

in my tex.vim config file.

But it's produce error `E486: Pattern not found: Tex_SmartQuoteOpen` "\enquote{"

Any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: that is possible, but \enquote is already  semantic :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very easy: just escape the `\`.

```
let g:Tex_SmartQuoteOpen="\\enquote{"
let g:Tex_SmartQuoteClose="}"
```